# C++/WinRT Error C2872 'IUnknown': ambiguous symbol when using namespace

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, bluetooth-lowenergy, c++-winrt

C++, WinRT, VS2017, Windows10, Bluetooth LE

I have a stand-alone C++/WinRT VS2017 console app that was used for testing code to control a Bluetooth LE device. That console app works and I am now in the process of moving that code into an existing C++ MFC VS2017 app which also works.

In the existing MFC app I first installed the NuGet cppwinrt package that I used in the test console app (no problems)

I then put the various WinRt header files that were in the console app's pch.h into the MFC's stdafx.h file

```
#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp") 
#include <condition_variable>
#include "winrt\Windows.Foundation.h" 
#include "winrt\Windows.Storage.Streams.h" 
#include "winrt\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.h" 
#include "winrt\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.h"
#include "winrt\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile.h"
```

So far, so good.  The MFC app still compiles without problems.  However, I then put the "using namespace" entries, that were at the top of the console app's .cpp file, into the MFC's ...View.cpp and that is when I get the compile problems

```
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Bluetooth;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::GenericAttributeProfile;
```

The compile error I get is:

> Error C2872   'IUnknown': ambiguous symbol  MyMFCApp  c:\program files
> (x86)\microsoft visual
> studio\2017\professional\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h    3456

I see that IUnknown seems to be fairly universal throughout Windows APIs.  How should I go about clearing up this error?

Comment: Just don't use `using namespace`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles  I'm fairly sure I need to but I haven't tried.  I will add a call to one of the WinRT functions and see what happens.

In the meantime, I played around with the "using namespace" and found that it was only 2 that were causing the problem.


//using namespace Windows::Foundation; // errors IUnknown
//using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation; // errors IUnknown

Comment: Make sure to `#include <unknwn.h>` ahead of any C++/WinRT header files.

Comment: Also, the first three `using namespace` statements are odd. The third one should merge the same namespace as the combination for the first two. You should be able to just remove the third line altogether (`using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;`).

Answer (score 2):

@AlanBirtles answer seems to have solved the problem.  In the console app I could not compile without these `using namespace` entries so I just assumed that I would also need them in the MFC app.  As I mentioned in my comment above, all of the namespaces compiled in the MFC app except for the two `Foundation` namespaces.

```
//using namespace Windows::Foundation; // errors IUnknown
//using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation; // errors IUnknown
```

I left the rest and commented these two out and then added the code to create the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher`, attach a callback for the `watcher.Received()` and let it find my device. It ran fine.  I have not yet tried with the rest of the namespaces commented out but I will.

I did try @IInspectable suggestion for using the  `#include <unknwn.h>` before all of the WinRT namespaces.  I put that in at the top and then uncommented one of the two `Foundation` namespaces but still got the ambiguous `IUnknown` error.

So the answer seems to be (for my situation anyway) that the namespaces were not necessary...at least the two `Foundation` namespaces.

Thanks for the help.  It is really appreciated.

Comment: As a follow up I did need the other namespaces.  All except the two "Foundation" namespaces mentioned in the answer.  I commented them all out and got piles of compile errors.  I uncommented them one by one and kept getting compile errors until they were all uncommented (except the Foundation ones).  So I guess that answers that... Thanks again.

Comment: Since MFC projects generated from a wizard use precompiled headers by default, make sure to `#include <unknwn.h>` from the *pch.h* file. Placing this include directive into any other compilation unit or header file will not have the desired effect.

Comment: My C++ MFC app never had a pch.h but has a stdafx.h.  I have put the includes from the C++/WinRT console app's pch.h into the stdafx.h file instead.  I will include that unknown.h file just to be sure.

Comment: The specific file that's used to create a precompiled header is set through the [`/Yc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/yc-create-precompiled-header-file) compiler option. Make the changes to the file that's set through this option in your project.

Comment: Thanks,  I had the Pecompiled Header File set to stdafx.h but the Precompiled Header was set to Not Using Precompiled Headers....

Comment: Could you re-enable PCH support, or, alternatively slap an `#include <unknwn.h` directive as the first statement into every .cpp file? I believe that is the actual solution (working off of memory here) so it would be helpful to have that verified. Not that I'd think that C++/WinRT ever will attract a *lot* of users, but the few of us that use this library would certainly appreciate any bit of help.

Comment: Give me a little time to get to that but I will.  As is my lot in life I am in the middle of another problem that I <think> I just solved so let me finish that first and I will test this out.

Comment: I have set the Precompiled Header to stdafx.h with /Yc.  The only cpp file I am using WinRT code in right now is my ....View.cpp so, as a test, I put the include <unknwn.h> at the very top of that View cpp and then un-commented first the >using namespace Windows::Foundation</br> and then the >using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation </br> and tried to compile each time and each time I still got that IUnknows ambigious error.